# Building Go app

Tags: go

I just started learning golang and I want tried to build a hello world webpage  as per [here](http://mwholt.blogspot.com/2013/05/writing-go-golang-web-app-with-nginx.html).However when I use `run` or `build` via SSH i don't "regain" control of the prompt.

[image]

If I do `Ctrl + C` , my app no longer work , I think i am misunderstanding how Go work

Comment: Is the `index` your application's name? The compiled Go executable is normally just a regular executable that reads/writes to stdin/stdout, opens sockets, etc.

Comment: @AlexAtNet yes my app is named index.go

Comment: `index` is running in the foreground, `Ctrl+C` sends a SIGINT to `index` shutting down the process.

Comment: If that explanation doesn't help you enough, Go's http package starts a web server process. Your "index" file is an executable by itself, index.go isn't run by an interpreter or managed by a service like Apache or nginx. If you're looking for a way to make it run as a service, it's a bit more complicated and depends on your OS (and is more to do with systems administration than programming in Go). You could use `ctrl+z` to send the process to the background (`fg` brings it back), but the process will still be tied to your current session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you `nohup` the process it will run "indefinitely" until you call `kill <PID>` on it. Further, if it binds to a HTTP port you'll need to remember to kill the running process else your new/rebuilt process won't be able to bind.

Using something simple like Supervisor ([guide here](http://elithrar.github.io/article/running-go-applications-in-the-background/)) or daemontools is a more sane way to run manage processes. Here's a quick Supervisor config for a Go application:

```
[program:index]
command=/home/yourappuser/bin/index
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
# the user your app should run as (i.e. *not* root!)
user=yourappuser
# where your application runs from
directory=/srv/www/yourapp.com/
# environmental variables
environment=APP_SETTINGS="/srv/www/yourapp.com/prod.env"
redirect_stderr=true
# the name of the log file.
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/yourapp.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
```

This will work if your Go application doesn't need to bind to port 80. If it does, use `setcap` (and never run your application as root) with `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /home/yourappuser/bin/index`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) for that like this:

`nohup ./index &`

`nohup` used to prevent termination of the process after user logout and `&` used to start process in background.
After it you can exit from console.

Comment: Note that if you `nohup` the process it will run "indefinitely" until you call `kill <PID>` on it. Further, if it binds to a HTTP port you'll need to remember to kill the running process else your new/rebuilt process won't be able to bind. Using something simple like Supervisor ([guide here](https://elithrar.github.io/article/running-go-applications-in-the-background/)) or daemontools is a more sane way to run manage processes.

Comment: @elithrar that's exactly what i needed .Thank you for your guide and kindly post  the above as an answer to my question so that i can accept it